# Joomla 3.9.1 publish/unpublish no longer working (custom components)

Tags: custom-component, joomla-3.9

I've recently upgraded my joomla site to 3.9.1, and now my custom components publish/unpublish buttons aren't working and I can't figure out why. The database column is called "state" and this is the code which was working up until the upgrade:

```
JToolbarHelper::publish('items.publish', 'JTOOLBAR_PUBLISH', true);
JToolbarHelper::unpublish('items.unpublish', 'JTOOLBAR_UNPUBLISH', true);
```

These buttons used to work and they would publish / unpublish the items, now I get this message:

**0 items successfully published**

I'm not sure where exactly the code is which tells it to update the status of the item, but for some reason it's not working anymore.

Comment: Guys after upgrading to joomla 3.9 i faced the same problem as above. I am now facing a similar problem with creating a new file, it saves the record but the id returned is 0

Comment: @Leanne In case you are unaware, you can ask the Stack Exchange administrators to merge your two accounts.  I've not personally done this, but it is possible.  https://stackoverflow.com/users/92129/souliebaby  advice: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/352329

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your table's constructor use `setColumnAlias()` to define the actual column name:

```
public function __construct($db)
{
    parent::__construct('#__example', 'id', $db);

    $this->setColumnAlias('published', 'state');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting this error now: Error: 0 Call to undefined method EmploymentModelitems::setColumnAlias()

Comment: You seem to have added this to the model, not to the table class. Tables are typically found in `administrator/components/com_example/tables` directory.

Comment: lol I had indeed, thank you for your help, that worked!!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Only for me, the unpublish worked, and the publish did not.
Solved by deleting rows from the table file.

```
if ( empty( $array['published'] ) ){
    $array['published'] = '1';
}
```

Comment: While this may have worked for your project, I am wary about suggesting that researchers manually overwrite the `published` value if it is "not set or zero/falsey".  I mean, if `$array['published'] = 0` or `$array['state'] = 0`, then your script will always declare `$array['published'] = 1` -- this kind of defeats the purpose of the toggleable value.  Comparing this advice to Sharky's, I'd say it is a bad idea to ignore the database data coming from `published/state`.

Comment: If `$array['published']` is empty, the default value is provided in the database. I repeat that this `if ( empty( $array['published'] ) ){ $array['published'] = '1';}` gives a bug when working with `JHtml::_( 'jgrid.published', $item->state, $i, 'tickets.', $canChange, 'cb' );`   Just as the error of the buttons on the toolbar